# Как создать такую таблицу в css?

Tags: html, css

Я так понимаю нужно использовать display: table[image: вот такую]

Comment: Зависит от того, с помощью чего верстаете. Нет единого ответа на ваш вопрос, их много может быть. Если спрашиваете как это верстать - идите смотрите уроки

Comment: Чем этот блок отличается от других? 2 строки по 3 колонки! Или Вы хотите чтобы за Вас все сделали?! Приведите код что Вы уже сделали и что не получилось!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, используя **grid** верстку(flex,table..), но судя по всему вам необходимо в целом почитать материал по css. Вот вам как пример:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;  
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.container div {
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
<div class='container'>

  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение на flex. Откорректируй стили так, как тебе нужно.

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 0.5%;
}
.flex-item {
    width: 33%;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item img {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-item h2 {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.flex-item p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.main h1 {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.main p {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.chertocka {
    height: 2px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<h1>Название</h1>
<p>Описание</p>
<div class="chertocka"></div>
<ul class="flex-container">
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
<li class="flex-item">
<img src="https://www.icon.com.mt/wp-content/themes/icon/img/logo.svg" alt="Описание рисунка если надо, если нет, оставляешь пустым">
<h2>Название</h2>
<p>Описание</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```